# Monopoly - Community chest paying for houses

Tags: monopoly

On community chest card, I was told to pay 400 per each house I own due to insurance price hike.
I owned 12 houses, so this adds up to 4800.

Now - as I didn't have enough money, I mortgaged some other properties, and sold 3 houses back to the bank (leaving me with 9 houses).
Do I still have to pay 4800 for 12 houses, or is it only 3600 now as I only own 9 houses now?
Bit silly paying insurance price hike for houses I don't own anymore.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

You can sell property to raise the amount that needs to be paid. The amount was 4800.

Think of it as paying in arrears

Answer (score 6):

You should take it as a bill on the moment of possesing the houses. So unfortunately you should resolve the payment first by all means possible before anything else is taken into account.